# Is it possible to process Apple Notification Message?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I need to know If I can process an Apple notification message before the user of the iPhone can read it?

What I am trying to do here is, I want to filter the message before the user see the AlertView  etc.. because my server will be sending a hidden message inside the payload for invoking other services later on

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You CANNOT do this outside of your application. Apple delivers the message to the user before the rest of the applications. You can touch it only if the user decides to open the alert.

You CAN do this if the user gets the message while inside your app ( in this case there is no alert message anyway)

Comment: Sorry to be the bearer of bad news. What are you trying to do?

Comment: The server is going to send me a push notification letting me know that some of my friends has joined the app, using his phone number. and all I want to do is to match the number on the iPhone and match the name of this contact.

Comment: I see what you mean. Yeah it's a shame apple doesn't let you do that sort of thing ( Android does btw in case you were wondering ). Guess you'll have to settle for having the user poll the server for this when he opens the app...

Answer (score 0):

you can certainly do the thing you want to do if you application is in active/foreground state.
at this stage, your appdelegate's `didreceiveremotenotification` is called with the notification payoad and there you can filter whatever you want.

in other cases - when application is not in foreground, you cannot filter PUSH notification messagebox as it is generated by iOS.

i hope this will clear ur understanding on APNS.